# How can I make printed versions of a site not be affected by screen size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing-web-page

I am working on a website that generates reports and then these can be printed on PDF. These reports are dynamic, and show different information every time, so I cannot create the PDFs beforehand, they need to be printed from what the user gets on the screen.

I am using Bootstrap and [this fix](https://blog.donnierayjones.com/2014/10/fix-bootstrap3-printing/) so that the mobile layout is not rendered on print.

However, I noticed that the print version is still affected by the web version, so if a user is generating the report on a very small screen, it will still print a mobile version.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
   <div id="chart1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
   <div id="chart2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <div id="chart3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The "sm" classes are for print, but if the screen is showing the charts all on different rows because it's a smaller screen, the print version will show it this way, even when the letter paper size could accommodate all three graphs in one row.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: there is a .hidden-print class in bootstrap to do just that

Comment: But I don't want to hide any of these divs, I want them to print exactly the way I put them on the row with the "sm" classes. @BrianMcCall

Comment: why have col-sm? they are the same at col-md in your case

Answer (score 0):

@media Queries are responsible for this
You should apply a custom media query to overwrite bootstrap behavior.
Bootstrap is good if you have no UI and need something quick, but in custom development it's more a pain in the ass than a helper.

Can try this super generic fix

```
@media print {
div.col-md-3 {
  display:block;float:left;width:25%;
}
div.col-md-6{
  display:block;float:left;width:50%;
}
}
```

However, I would give them specific classes, unless you are fine with ALL the .col-md-3 and .col-md-6 classes being changed for print. (alternatively, edit bootstrap and add in your media queries for print or change their defined queries for print)
Fine tune and adjust width as needed,